# "Inheriting" Move Operators?

Tags: c++, move

I was watching a Bjarne Stroustrup talk and the section was on move operators and their benefits.

He mentions [here](https://youtu.be/86xWVb4XIyE?t=2554) that an explicit move constructor such as:

```
Matrix(Matrix&& a)
{
    rep = a.rep;
    a.rep = {};
}
```

Is "c-style" and "cryptic".

He then goes on to say that in a lot of cases, writing copy/move operators can be avoided; he provides the following example [here](https://youtu.be/86xWVb4XIyE?t=2601):

```
class Matrix
{
    vector<double> elem;
    // ... matrix access...
}
```

He states that this Matrix class "inherits" resource management from vector and that the copy/move constructors are implicitly generated it.

Could someone help clarify what he means by this?  How would I take a Matrix object and utilize move semantics if I didn't define a move operator for Matrix?

Comment: The basic concept for move constructors is like that for copy constructors. If your member variables are all copy-constructible, there is no need for a user-defined copy constructor for the class. Same sort of thing for moves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move constructors are implicitly defined when

> - X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

So in the case of `Matrix` the move constructor is implicitly defined.  And the implicit move constructor does its best to move its data members.  And `std::vector` is movable, so it moves the instance of the vector in the `Matrix` struct.

Answer (score 0):

Because [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is a class that has already this functionality implemented. By using that as your storage for `Matrix`, when you are about to play around with `Matrix` and its data, `std::vector` will be involved, bringing into the game the functionality I mentioned above.